# Cannot pass parameter when attempting prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to learn prepared statements right now in PHP/MYSQL because of many suggestions around here. I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\create.php on line 57
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? I've been searching around and I can't find anything that will help me solve this.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once '../config.php';

// Check to see if the title was entered from new.php
if ($_POST['title'])
{
$title = $_POST['title'];
} else {

echo "No title was entered. Please go back. <br />";
}

// Check to see if the body was entered from new.php
if ($_POST['body'])
{
$body = $_POST['body'];
} else {

echo "No body was entered. Please go back. <br />";
}

// Get the date
$date = time();

// ID = NULL because of auto-increment
$id = 'NULL';

// If magic_quotes_gpc returns true then it's enabled on the serever and all variables   will be
// automatically escaped with slashes. If it isn't true then it's done manually

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$title = addslashes($title);
$body = addslashes($body);
$date = addslashes($date);
}

// Connect to the database

$db = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');

// Check to see if the connection works
if ($db->connect_errno)
{
echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again.';
exit;
}

// Prepared statement for a query to place something in the database
if(!($stmt = $db->prepare("insert into pages (id, title, body, date) values (?,?,?,?)")))
{
echo "Prepare failed: (" .$db->errno . ")" . $db->error;
}

// THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I'M RECEIVING THE ERROR!!!!!!!!
if (!$stmt->bind_param('isss', ''.$id.'', ''.$title.'',''.$body.'',''.$date.''))
{
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" .$stmt->errno. ")" . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute())
{
echo "Execute failed: (" .$stmt->errno . ") " .$stmt->error;
}

$db->close;

?>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove id from the insert and the param list as it's an auto_incrementing field?

Comment: @TommyBs When I take out the auto-incrementing field I still get the same error

Comment: Sorry my first comment I was thinking of PDO and not mysqli hence I removed it. I'm not sure you need the quote marks around your variables in the bind_param part either. But what happens if you remove the $id as I stated above

Comment: If I remove $id, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the corresponding [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) documentation. More precisely, have a look at the function's definition:

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

Notice the `mixed &$var1` part? This basically states that your paramters are passed by reference and not by value (which would look like `mixed $var1` - the `&` makes the difference).

Now, the problem with your invocation is that you are trying to pass an **expression** rather than a variable by reference. From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

> The following things can be passed by reference:

- Variables, i.e. foo($a)
- New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
- References returned from functions, [...]

The simple remedy is to first call the binding with uninitialized variables which are then assigned your processed input data, i.e.

```
// Prepared statement for a query to place something in the database
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into pages (id, title, body, date) values (?,?,?,?)");

if ( !$stmt ) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" .$db->errno . ")" . $db->error;
}

if ( !$stmt->bind_param('isss', $stmt_id, $stmt_title, $stmt_body, $stmt_date) ) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" .$stmt->errno. ")" . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt_id    = (int) $id;
$stmt_title = (string) $title;
$stmt_body  = (string) $body;
$stmt_date  = (string) $date;

if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" .$stmt->errno . ") " .$stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: Really can't thank you enough for such a detailed and great response. It works fine and I learned what I wanted to learn. Thank you very much.